# How to change the space between histograms in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently using `df.hist(alpha = .5)`, but all of the subplots are too close from each other, like this:

[Histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b76K7.png)

Which way is better to change the space between them?
Or is better to plot each one in a separate .png file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One simple way is to manipulate `figsize` and add `pyplot.tight_layout`. Below is the example.

Without adjustment:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6400)
                  .reshape((100, 64)), columns=['col_{}'.format(i) for i in range(64)])
df.hist(alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

You will get this as you showed:

[image]

In contrast, if you add `figsize` (with arbitrary size) and `pyplot.tight_layout` like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6400)
                  .reshape((100, 64)), columns=['col_{}'.format(i) for i in range(64)])
df.hist(alpha=0.5, figsize=(20, 10))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In this case you will get more aligned view:

[image]

Hope this helps.